# render div using JQuery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, render

I have a div that refresh every 3 sec but when the the div refresh the css is not render. This is my code.

in html

```
 <div id="statusbar"></div>
```

in js

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
update2();
function update2() {
        $('#statusbar').load('statusbar.php');
        $('#statusbar').trigger('create');
        statustimeout = setTimeout("update2()", 3000);
}
});
```

Im using JQuery mobile. I'm newbie so be please specific. TY in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this incorrectly.

Load is asynchronous **AJAX** function so you can't just call **trigger('create')** directly after. Basically code will never wait for async functions to end, code execution will simply go further and **trigger('create')** will not have anything to enhance.

To do this correctly you need to execute load function and wait for successful callback to trigger, something like this:

```
$('#statusbar').load("statusbar.php", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
    $('#statusbar').trigger('create');
});
```

Second thing, you are using **trigger('create')** in the wrong way. It should be triggered on **data-role="content"** div because it main purpose is to enhance whole content, not part of it. Just like that **trigger('pagecreate')** is used to enhance whole page and it should be called on **data-role="page"** div. If you are using jQuery Mobile 1.4 then you should use **[enhanceWithin()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/)**.

So everything should look like this:

```
$('#statusbar').load("statusbar.php", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
    $('#statusbar').enhanceWithin();
});
```

Comment: Hi @user206250 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: ya! thanks i use the first code and its working :) ill try the second but the 1st one is already working! TY @Gajotres

Comment: **.enhanceWithin();** is not working i got an error _undefined is not a function_ pls help :(

Comment: Then simply use first solution. Tell me one thing, what jQuery Mobile version are you using?

Comment: now its working i have an error to the page that i was loading. Im using 1.4.2 TY!

Answer (score 1):

`update2()` cannot be a string, it needs to be a function (so just put `function(){ update2() }` instead of `"update2()"`). Also your function call needs to be after the definition.

See [this fiddle for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/8QzrX/2/)

Comment: E Rullmann thats not the problem the page is reloading even if that code. my problem now is the css is not applying in the `<div id ='status'>`

Answer (score 0):

E Rullmann summed it up. You'll want to do something like that. Or maybe consider doing something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var update2 = function () {

      $('#statusbar').load('statusbar.php');
      $('#statusbar').trigger('create');

   };

   setTimeout(function () {
      update2(); 
      /* this function isn't hoisted, 
         so you can only call it after it's declared */
      }, 5000 /*your timeout value*/);
});
```